# Can't launch jd-gui on ubuntu 14.04 64 bits

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded `jd-gui` from http://jd.benow.ca/ i.e. `jd-gui-0.3.5.linux.i686.tar.gz`

Extracted it.

Now if I try to launch the jd-gui from double clicking on the icon, nothing happens, but using console I get following error:

```
~/Downloads/jd-gui-0.3.5.linux.i686$ ./jd-gui 
./jd-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out

I have to install the correct version of the [libgtk2.0-0 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgtk2.0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for my release and architecture.  for my  which was missing in my machine.

commands I used are :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```

Comment: +1 and a quick note: this requires the enablement of a foreign architecture as the first step: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`. Apparently you already did that earlier but others with the same issue may not. (Adding an existing architecture changes nothing, so it doesn't hurt to run the command anyway.)

Comment: Edited in an attempt to make more useful to a wider number of cases and future proof. @DavidFoerster since there are packages available for virtually every architecture that Ubuntu supports, I'm not sure your comment is still valid. Cheers!

Comment: @ElderGeek: The question is specifically about an i386 executable that requires this library. (Although it would probably complain about a missing `libc.so.6` too if the architecture were disabled.)